# Trying to implement autocomplete Chips with Angular Material. Getting cannot read property 'nextTick' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have followed the chips demo with autocomplete on [Demo Chips Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips).
When removing a "chip" I get the error:
*Cannot read property **`nextTick`** of `undefined`*.
Even the tutorial page throws the error. Do you have any solution for that problem?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Yeah it does. Do you have any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: I'm tempted to have a look at the source to fix it out of curiosity. Would that be acceptable? It would mean loading an edited version of angular-material.js rather than the one from bower/npm.

Comment: Hm this is not really acceptable neither scalable. I mean they might fix that bug in the future. I think I will live with the bug for now since it does not affect anything else

Comment: Have no bug here with latest chrome. Which browser do you use ? Could you provide reproducable codepen?

Comment: I just downloaded the newest version and it is still buggy. I am using a Macbook btw. On the mentioned website go to: Use md-autocomplete to build an ordered set of chips. Add Broccoli and delete it and you will see the error in the console. @ValeryKozlov

Comment: Yeah it was identified as a bug. According to Github the issue was addressed and closed [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9520). Hopefully it will be part of the next release :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mark is right
if you want a quick workaround this add this code in your **angular-material.js** file

```
    /** @type {$mdUtil} */
   this.$mdUtil = $mdUtil;
```

**Problem:** $mdUtils is being passed into the constructor but not being saved on this.

for a reference take a look this like [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9928)

The commit which fixes this issue is [a3b3e7b](https://github.com/angular/material/commit/a3b3e7b037fb02acae5c1d979e8373d7e8c93dfd) which will be available in next release.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9520) in the Angular Material GitHub repository, the fix for this problem is available in HEAD and will be included in the upcoming 1.1.2 release.